# Replace all fonts in PowerPoint 2016?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

In PowerPoint 2010 I had the option for replacing all fonts in an entire presentation.

[image]

Now we updated to Office 365, and in PowerPoint 2016  if I go to Replace Fonts I don't have the option for replacing all fonts, but only to replace a particular one.

[image]

Let's say I have a presentation with differents font used across all of the slides, how can I replace all fonts without even knowing which different fonts I have, like the option in PowerPoint 2010 ?? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialog box you used to have is not a standard PowerPoint dialog. I'd guess that you had an add-in installed that supplied its own dialog box, but don't have it installed into your new version of Office.

Comment: I think you are right, It might be a ThinkCell feature, what is odd is that this dialog box is no in the ThinkCell "panel".

Comment: Office add-ins can install themselves pretty much where they like on the Ribbon, and can even make existing tabs/buttons invisible and replace them with their own.